# Passing data from Django to D3

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, d3.js

I'm trying to write a very basic bar graph using Django and D3.js. I have an object called play with a datetime field called date. What I want to do is show number of plays over time grouped by month. Basically I have two questions:

1. How do I get these grouped by month with a count of the number of plays in that month
2. What is the best way to get this information from Django into something usable by D3.

Now I have looked at some other answers on here and have tried

```
json = (Play.objects.all().extra(select={'month': "extract(month FROM date)"})
.values('month').annotate(count_items=Count('date')))
```

This gets close to trhe information I want but when I try to output it in the template it comes out as the following (with Ls) on the end of the months. This means that obviously it isn't valid js (no qoutes) and I don't really want the Ls on the end there anyway.

Template:

```
    <script>
        var test ={{ json|safe }};
        alert("test");

    </script>
```

output:

```
var test = [{'count_items': 10, 'month': 1L}, {'count_items': 5, 'month': 2L}];
```

I have also tried json.dumps on this data but I get told it isn't valid JSON. This feels like it should be a lot more straightforward to do in Django so maybe I am headed down the worng path entirely.

Comment: Are you using Django 1.7? I've already a custom solution to you, just to verify that we are using the same version.

Comment: On 1.4.1  upgrading as we speak and then I'll try out your answer.

Comment: Ok. It's because [django.http.JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) was introduced on 1.7.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Since D3.js v3 has a nice collection of [methods to load data from external resources](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/API-Reference.md#loading-external-resources)¹, It's better to you not embed data into your page, you just load it.

This will be an answer by example.

Let's start with a model definition:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models


class Play(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

A urlconf:

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url


from .views import graph, play_count_by_month

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', graph),
    url(r'^api/play_count_by_month', play_count_by_month, name='play_count_by_month'),
]
```

We are using two urls, one to return the html (view `graph`), and the other url (view `play_count_by_month`) as an api to return only data as JSON.

And finally our views:

```
# views.py
from django.db import connections
from django.db.models import Count
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Play


def graph(request):
    return render(request, 'graph/graph.html')


def play_count_by_month(request):
    data = Play.objects.all() \
        .extra(select={'month': connections[Play.objects.db].ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'date')}) \
        .values('month') \
        .annotate(count_items=Count('id'))
    return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
```

Here we defined an view to return our data as JSON, note that I changed extra to be database agnostic, since I did tests with SQLite.

And follows our `graph/graph.html` template that shows a graph of play counts by month:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse; // for dates like "2014-01-01"
//var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00Z").parse;  // for dates like "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.month); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.count_items); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("{% url "play_count_by_month" %}", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.month = parseDate(d.month);
    d.count_items = +d.count_items;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.month; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.count_items; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Play count");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will return a nice graph like this (random data):
[image: Graph of Play counts by month]

**Update 1**: D3 v4 will move the code to load external data to a dedicated lib, please see [d3-request](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#requests-d3-request).
**Update 2**: In order to help, I've put all files together into an example project, on github: [github.com/fgmacedo/django-d3-example](https://github.com/fgmacedo/django-d3-example)

Comment: Hmmm so I tried putting all of this together and all I get is  the left part of the graph (no lines or labels). here is what my play_count_by_month page output looks like:

    `[{"count_items": 10, "month": "2013-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, {"count_items": 5, "month": "2013-02-01T00:00:00Z"}]`

I didn't see any JS errors or any issues on the network side (it looks like it made the request ok)

Comment: There's a problem with the date format. My result of `play_count_by_month`is like this: `[{"count_items": 731, "month": "2014-01-01"}, {"count_items": 404, "month": "2014-02-01"}]`. You can try change the `parseDate` function on graph.html to this: `var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00Z").parse;`

Comment: I tried putting all this together exactly, and I got an error saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined(anonymous function) @ (index):63event @ d3.v3.js:504respond @ d3.v3.js:1950

Which was at the data.forEach(function(d) { line

Comment: I also implemented this exactly and it didn't work, I think something needs to happen in `settings.py` is it so?

Comment: Hi @s.matthew.english, in order to help, I've put all together into an example project, on github: https://github.com/fgmacedo/django-d3-example . Please let me know!

Answer (score 5):

I loved what fernando-macedo put together and it got me to a certain point with my data.

However I struggled with filtering of data as opposed to passing the entire dataset via this api setup. This is very similar to other peoples problem of passing JSON data from a Queryset and Pavel Patrin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29724571/6576690) helped me with that.

So this will now allow people to *filter* their data and send it as a json for use in d3. Now I am using the same hypothetical example but it should work for

```
# views.py
from django.db import connections
from django.db.models import Count
# from django.http import JsonResponse  #no longer needed
from django.shortcuts import render
import json


from .models import Play


def graph(request):
    data = Play.objects.filter(name__startswith='Test') \ #change here for filter. can be any kind of filter really
        .extra(select={'month': connections[Play.objects.db].ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'date')}) \
        .values('month') \
        .annotate(count_items=Count('id'))
    formattedData=json.dumps([dict(item) in list(data)]) #This is a two-fer. It converts each item in the Queryset to a dictionary and then formats it using the json from import json above
    #now we can pass formattedData via the render request
    return render(request, 'graph/graph.html',{'formattedData':formattedData})
```

Now to get that appropriately on the other side (the html side)

```
<script src="{% static 'd3.v3.min.js' %}" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'> // the type text/javascript is key here!
var data= {{formattedData|safe}} // now you can just reference data with no need to use d3.json.
//Critical that there is no quotation marks here and this is where you denote safe!

//Insert the rest
//of Fernando's code here
//minus the last '});'
//as that ends the d3.json function call
</script>
```

Anyways, I hope this saves someone some time with Django and/or D3 as this solves two issues at once.